# Python setup.py entry point spaces in name

Tags: python, click, setup.py

I have a setup.py like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  name="exmpl",
  version='0.1',
  py_modules=['core'],
  install_requires=[
    'click',
  ],
  entry_points='''
    [console_scripts]
    exmpl=core:main
  ''',
)
```

However, I want the command line tool to have options like git does, for example - exmpl init, or exmpl commit -m "some commit message".

How can I do this with setup.py and the click library?

Comment: The technique you're wanting to use is generally called 'subcommands', and it won't be listed in setup.py. Your program name will be `exmpl`, but `core:main` will have to understand how to process the subcommands, and you can either write your own or use the click module you've installed.

Comment: Thank you Simon!! It's exactly the term for it which I didn't know and so searching google didn't yield much. Now that I know what it's called, I've found what I wanted on the click documentation. Thank you.